# Does managedObjectContext.object(with:) always refetch data if another (private) managedObjectContext changed and saved it?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

*(I'm sorry if this question is kind of confusing/imprecise. I'm just learning advanced CoreData usage and I don't know the terminology and stuff very well).*

I have a singleton `Game` that holds certain data you need during the game. For example, you can access `currentSite` (`Site` is a CoreData `Entity`) from there to get the `Site` the user is currently at:

```
// I created the Site in a background queue (when the game started), then saved the objectID and here I load the objectID
public var currentSiteObjectID: NSManagedObjectID {
        let objectIDuri = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: Keys.forGameObject.currentSiteObjectIDURI)!
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: objectIDuri)!
    }

// managedObjectContext is the one running on the main queue    
public var currentSite: Site! {
        return managedObjectContext.object(with: currentSiteObjectID) as! Site
    }
```

You see, I retrieve the `currentSite` by using the `managedObjectContext.object(with:)` method.

The documentation of this method says:

> Returns the object for a specified ID.
>
> If the object is not registered
>   in the context, it may be fetched or returned as a fault. (...)

I'm not quite sure about the following:

```
// Each Site has resources that you can access like this
print(Game.shared.currentSite!.resourceSet!.iron)

appDelegate.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
    let currentSite = context.object(with: Game.shared.currentSiteObjectID) as! Site

    // Here I increase the iron resource
    currentSite.resourceSet!.iron += 42
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("\(error.debugDescription)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(Game.shared.currentSite!.resourceSet!.iron)
    }
}
```

The second `print` function is using the `managedObjectContext` of the main queue (which is different to the private one used inside `performBackgroundTask {...}`).

It actually does print:

```
50 // the start value
92
```

My question: Is it guaranteed that `managedObjectContext.object(with:)` returns the current object (that is up-to-date), even if it has been changed in another `context`? The documentation says that it will be fetched if it's a new object that's not known to the `context`.
But what if an object changes?

I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence that the example code from above is working like expected.

Thanks for any help/explanation! I'm eager to learn about this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not guaranteed. If managed object is already registered in context then it will return this object. What's more, if object with given id (NSManagedObjectId) doesn't exist in persistent store then your app will crash as soon as you try to use any of its properties.

Comment: But I'm using a print statement before changing the value. Doesn't this mean that the managedObject **is** registered in the context? And after the execution it does give me the updated object.
Also, I do make sure that it's a valid objectID.

Comment: do you hold any strong reference to managed object? Context keeps strong reference only if object has some changes that don't be saved to persistent store

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you hold strong reference to object, then this object will not be deallocated so object will be registered in context (you will not see any changes from other context, unless you merge contexts after updates). If you don't hold strong reference (and object do not have any pending changes) then ARC will dealloc it and it will be unregistered from context so you will see all changes from other context (if changes were saved to persistent store) because fresh 'version' will be fetched from persistent store

Comment: Okay, so 'managedObjectContext.object(with:)' will only give me the up-to-date view if I don't have a strong reference on the 'Site' object, right? But is there a more convenient way to get the up-to-date version with the main context?

Comment: If you don't have a strong reference AND object do not have any pending changes. Yes there are more convenient ways, but this is topic for chapter rather than comment on the stack :p. Look at the NSFetchRequest.

Comment: You mean I have to refetch every time I want to access `currentSite`? But I don't know any way to fetch an object with its objectID

Comment: you don't have to, there are other ways. But if you want to fetch (refresh) every time then u can use `NSPredicate(format: "self == %@", objectID)`. But u can also merge context if some changes appears. https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506606-mergechanges

Comment: Actually, I'm reading about merging the contexts right now :D Sounds like exactly what I wanted. The only thing I don't understand is how to post ` NSManagedObjectContextDidSave`. In Xcode, it doesn't even recognise this as Notification.Name

Comment: Nvm, I just found it. The thing now is: How can I add an observer for this notification, if there's a new private `context` every time I call `performBackgroundTask`?

Comment: notification is posted by CoreData. You need to handle this notification and use `mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave notification: Notification)` on your context.

Comment: Okay thank you. I just tested it: I set a strong reference on `currentSite` and (as you said) it printed the old version of the `managed object`. Then I implemented this merging and it gave me the up-to-date version. A step in the right direction! :) But I'm having trouble implementing this inside `performBackgroundTask`, not sure where to place the observer for this. But for that I'm gonna open another question I guess, as this one is technically answered by you. Thanks for that!